# Access 2007 to mysql migration using mysql workbench 8

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, mysql-workbench

While migrating with migration wizard It uses ODBC 64 bits
so in source It does not show DSN created with ODB 32 bits.
I don't have 64 bit driver for access
The database is very large 1.5 gb
I need to resolve the issue. or need another way to migrate

Comment: Why can't you install the 64bit ODBC driver? Are you using an older MS Access version, which only comes with a 32bit ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as easy as it should be. The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html) tell us to use the x86 version of the Workbench. You can't use Workbench 8 as it is distributed only as x64 app.

The trick is to to find the last x86 version of the Workbench in [previous GA -Releases](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), what is 6.2.5 **not 6.3.10**

Before you can install this, you have to uninstall your x64 version of the Workbench.

After that you can install the x86 version just downloaded, run the migration wizard and connect to your x86 `Ms Access` Database with ODBC 32-Bit Administrator.

Comment: Thanks.
I installed 6.3.10, but I get error 
CREATE command denied to user (for mysql)

Comment: Workbench 6.3.10,is availible as x86 app? I thought I read rhat they only distribute x64 apps from >= 6.3.User is root or is allowd to create DBs.?